# RAM dead or incompatible?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, compatibility

I have a new computer with the following configuration:

```
MB: ASUS Z97-K
CPU: Intel i3-4330 with stock fan
RAM: HyperX Predator Black 8GB DDR3 1866MHz CL9 Dual Channel Kit
GPU: GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 660 OC WindForce 2X 2GB DDR5 192-bit
PSU: Keep Out FX800 800W Gaming
```

The problem is that when I start the computer I do not get the POST beep that tells you all the components are OK and can't even enter the BIOS. If I remove the RAM I get the beep error that there is no RAM installed.
So I thought that the RAM might be the problem and I've asked a friend to borrow me a RAM module that runs at 1600MHz, CL9 and my computer started right away with that module.

Now the question is do you think that the RAM is dead or it is not compatible with my CPU (on Intel's site it says it supports 1333/1600 MHz memory)?

If it is not compatible, then how do memory with frequency higher than 2600 run on i7-6700K for example without having the BIOS configured before with XMP, just like you would have a fresh configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> Now the question is do you think that the RAM is dead or it is not compatible with my CPU (on Intel's site it says it supports 1333/1600 MHz memory)?

There's really no reason to think the issue is RAM incompatibility. It's unlikely that both RAM modules are dead (unless you got them from a really bad supplier) but it's possible one is. Try clearing the CMOS. Try testing the modules one at a time in different slots.

Try setting all RAM voltage and timing settings to the defaults (probably `auto`). Try upgrading the BIOS if you don't have the latest one.